vent plumbing question
my house has been getting some bad septic tank smell when it rains for the most part. i have 2 vent stacks 1 which is connected to my upstairs bathroom and im guessing the downstairs (basement)and a second which is connected to what seems to be the washer and kitchen. this goes underground to what seems to be the septic tank as well as the first one but they are about 10-14 feet apart.
here is a really rough pic i painted, notice the green circle thats where the 2 inch pipe that runs under the floor meets to connect both vent stacks is that necessary to be connected? bath 2 has all the vent piping per drain connected as normal 1 sink 1 toilet 1 tub. for bath 1 im not sure since i havent tore the walls open. my main concern for now is if that vent pipe that runs from 1 stack to the other should even be there since most are vented on its own.  

Are you more concerned about the connection between the vent stacks or the smell coming in the house?  I would think the vent connection is inconsequential. However I am not a pluming professional.  The smell should be from a dry Ptrap.  Be sure to run water in all the drains to fill the traps.

i checked all the traps none of them are dry and the smell isnt comming from the bathroom. the pipe going from one vent to the other my be broken,cracked, or  come loose. i was thinkning of cutting the pipe and capping it at the base where it branches off if it doesnt need to be connected as 1 entire system hence the 2 vents
